# name 'HttpsResponse' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpsResponse("Hello World, I am there")

# Create your views here.
```

Comment: It is `HttpResponse`, not `HttpsResponse`.

Comment: Bundle of thanks bro. Got it

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `return HttpsResponse("Hello World, I am there")`

Into this: `return HttpResponse("Hello World, I am there")`